# VBA Access: Files with Nulls

Tags: ms-access, macros, vba, ms-access-2010

**Overall Goal:**
Pull all files from folder > format files in staging table > copy staging table to master table > kill staging table > rinse and repeat until all files have been taken from folder, formatted and put into the master table.

**Issue:**
I have apparently not taken into account that some of the files sent to me will have blank worksheets (rather they may have a value that says "No Data" in cell A1). When my macro hits the "No Data" or blank sheet I get a Null error (94).

**What I've tried:**

- strF1Data = Nz(!ref_val)
- strF1Data = Nz(!ref_val,"")

**Suspicions:**
I think I can update the SQL UPDATE line to allow Nulls, but I feel like a more efficient solution would be to skip if null. However I have tried modifying the Do Until statement and had no luck...

**Possibly Worth Mentioning:**
The files have multiple worksheets. I learned this the hard way in finding this error on a random worksheet between several other worksheets that did have data.

**Code:** (to help save some space, I'm only giving the call files bit and formatting piece, I don't think the other pieces will be of any use. However if you would like them then let me know.)

**The overall macro (see next code sections for piece with error):**

```
Sub Pull_File_into_Staging_Table()
'Process:
    '1 - Loop through all files saved to specified folder making an internal list of the files
    '2 - Paste one files content to staging table at a time
    '3 - Format the information in the staging table
    '4 - Copy formatted staging table to 1Compare Table (master table)

Dim strFile As String 'Filename
Dim strFileList() As String 'File Array
Dim intFile As Integer 'File Number
Dim filename As String
Dim path As String
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
path = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Test\"
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset ' Moved from below
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb

'Loop through the folder & build file list
strFile = Dir(path & "*.xls")
While strFile <> ""
'add files to the list
intFile = intFile + 1
ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
strFileList(intFile) = strFile
strFile = Dir()
Wend

'see if any files were found
If intFile = 0 Then
MsgBox "No files found"
Exit Sub
End If

'cycle through the list of files
For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)
filename = path & strFileList(intFile)
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "Stage", filename, False

Call Format_Staging_Table
Call Copy_from_Stage_to_Master
Call Clear_Staging_Table

Next intFile
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

**The piece with the issue:**

```
Sub Format_Staging_Table()

Dim strFile As String 'Filename
Dim strFileList() As String 'File Array
Dim intFile As Integer 'File Number
Dim filename As String
Dim path As String
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
path = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Test\"
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset ' Moved from below
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb

CurrentDb.Execute ("ALTER TABLE Stage ADD COLUMN UPC Text, SR_Profit_Center Text, SR_Super_Label Text, SAP_Profit_Center Text, SAP_Super_Label Text;")

CurrentDb.TableDefs("Stage").Fields("F1").Name = "ref_val"


Dim ref_val As String
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 ref_val FROM Stage;", dbOpenDynaset)
ref_val = rs.Fields(0).Value
rs.Close

db.Execute "DELETE FROM [Stage] WHERE ref_val = '" & ref_val & "';"

Const YOUR_TABLE_NAME   As String = "Stage"
Dim SQL_UPDATE_DATA   As String
SQL_UPDATE_DATA = "SELECT *, ';' & '" & ref_val & "' FROM [" & YOUR_TABLE_NAME & "] WHERE SR_Profit_Center Is Null"

Dim strF1Data   As String
Dim varData     As Variant

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL_UPDATE_DATA)
With rs
    Do Until .EOF
        strF1Data = !ref_val
        varData = Split(strF1Data, ";")
        If UBound(varData) = 4 Then
            .Edit
            !ref_val = ref_val
            !UPC = varData(0)
            !SR_Profit_Center = varData(1)
            !SR_Super_Label = varData(2)
            !SAP_Profit_Center = varData(3)
            !SAP_Super_Label = varData(4)
            .Update
        End If
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With

Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Also I'm aware of the extra variable pieces, I will clean it up once I get it working.

**File Examples:**

**Working File:**

1. CE16041901
2. 00791558441123;US1K100017;CGR;US1K100001;UNKNOW
3. 00791558442328;US1K100017;CGR;US1K100001;UNKNOW
4. 00791558440720;US1K100017;CGR;US1K100001;UNKNOW
5. 00791558444629;US1K100017;CGR;US1K100001;UNKNOW
6. 00791558440522;US1K100017;CGR;US1K100001;UNKNOW
7. 00791558443325;US1K100017;CGR;US1K100001;UNKNOW

**Not Working File:**

1. CE16042001
2. 00791558334128;US1K100017;CGR;US1K100001;UNKNOW
3. 00791558159523;US1K100017;CGR;US1K100001;UNKNOW
4. 00602547736604;US1A100018;UR;US1A100018;US-RU

I appreciate any help. I ran with this as far as I could, but I am still very much a novice when it comes to access and vb. If you need more information or clarification please let me know and I'll do my best to provide/explain.

Answer (score 0):

No need to touch the staging table functions. Simply conditionally populate the `strFileList` array depending if Excel workbooks' first sheet contains *No Data* or empty cell. Recall Access VBA has complete access to all Excel objects via COM interface or Excel VBA reference and so can iteratively open workbooks. Hence, adjust your While/Wend loop accordingly:

```
Sub Pull_File_into_Staging_Table()

   '...same code...

   Dim objXL As Object
   Dim wb As Object

   Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

   strfile = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
   While strfile <> ""

       Set wb = objXL.Workbooks.Open(Path & strfile)

       If wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1") <> "No Data" AND  wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1") <> "" Then
           'add files to the list
           intFile = intFile + 1
           ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
           strFileList(intFile) = strfile
       End If
       strfile = Dir()

       wb.Close False
       Set wb = Nothing
   Wend
'...
```

Comment: It's giving me a 424 run time error, on line `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path & strFile)`

Comment: Indeed, I conflated Access and Excel VBA. When calling an external app you must qualify all objects. See edit using the `objXL` object.

Comment: Still no go, however it makes it back to the `strF1Data = !ref_val` code again. Giving the same error 94 as before.

Comment: I modified the `wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")` bit of code to be sheets(day1).Range("A1")...I tried both ways

Comment: There must be another issue with the workbooks other than *No Data* and empty cells. Do this, inside the later Do/Until loop, add at top `debug.Print !ref_val`. Re-run code and when it errors out, check the Immediate Window of VBA's IDE and see what the last file printed. That is the problem child. Open it and verify why it is erring out.

Comment: hmmm.....that was a good call. It doesn't seem to be stopping on the file that I thought. Although it doesn't make sense why I'm getting a Null error on this file. There are no apparent blanks. Any ideas now that you killed my first hypothesis?

Comment: Is it the first file? Does it have only one record? Look carefully at structure of the files that processed correctly before it and try to assess why. You posted no data, so I cannot know from this end.

Comment: It is not the first file, the files look nearly identical...the number of lines vary, but I can find examples that went through with less and went through with more. The number of characters in each field slightly varies, but again I can find those that match and those that have less. I added to me original post the file examples, if you can derive anything from that information. Or if it can lead you to anything else I might need to check. I appreciate all your help thus far!

Comment: In your *SQL_UPDATE_DATA* VBA string, try wrapping the refval with `Nz(refval, "")` in select statement (not in recordset loop). Somewhere there is a null value in Stage table and since you have abbreviated with asterisk, *, you need to rewrite columns explicitly. Of course with expression you need a new column alias.